# what is the top portion of a java method called

Tags: java

I can't recall what the top portion of a method is called, the portion that will show up when you mouse over a method, for example, the default top portion of a doPost method in a servlet is:

```
  /**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param   request   servlet request
 * @param   response  servlet response
 *
 * @throws  ServletException  DOCUMENT ME!
 * @throws  IOException       DOCUMENT ME!
 */
```

what is this top portion referred to as?

Comment: The comments ? The javadoc ?

Comment: Those are called as Javadoc. Are you talking about what those comments mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it starts with

```
/*
```

it is a plain comment block but it it starts with

```
/**
```

it means it is a Javadoc comment.

Comment: I always find this site very helpful if you want to remind yourself (or learn) how to write javadoc for your code:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html